# Extracting all the files of a selected extension from a zipped file

Tags: python

I am new to python, and I wanted to extract three single files of a different extensions each from a zipped file. I don't know their filenames, just their extensions.

Let's say that the following format exists:

> ---ZippedDirectory.zip
>
> ```
>  |_
>    RandomnameFile1.KnownFormat1
>  |_
>    RandomnameFile2.KnownFormat2
>  |_
>    RandomnameFile3.KnownFormat3
>  |...
> ```

I need to extract the above files, I only know the formats. There might be other files in this zipped archive.
 I am confused as to how to achieve this, Any help would be awesome!

Thanks!

Comment: See the [zipfile](https://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile.html) library, with some examples [here](https://pymotw.com/2/zipfile/)

Comment: One way with zipfile is to filter the files returned from `namelist()` and then use that list with `extractall()`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you should be able to do something like this

```
import zipfile


def main():
    archive = 'archive.zip'
    directory = './'
    extensions = ('.txt', '.pdf')
    zip_file = zipfile.ZipFile(archive, 'r')
    [zip_file.extract(file, directory) for file in zip_file.namelist() if file.endswith(extensions)]
    zip_file.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: This is working. How to convert Command Line Arguments and generate a .exe file?

Answer (score 3):

Mine is a simpler version of Jones'. Works for just one extension.

```
from zipfile import ZipFile

with ZipFile(r'C:\scratch\folder to process\try.zip') as theZip:
    fileNames = theZip.namelist()
    for fileName in fileNames:
        if fileName.endswith('py'):
            content = theZip.open(fileName).read()
            open(fileName, 'wb').write(content)
```